# Merge network of a router and an extender-router

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, home-networking

So, I see this question has been asked a couple of times already, but I none of the provided solutions worked for me (maybe I just don't know how to apply them).

I have a TP-LINK TL-WDR3600 connected to the internet cable from my ISP (I am provided with a PPPoE connection). Since the WiFi signal didn't reach the other corner of the house, I bought a TP-LINK Archer C2 AC750 which is now connected through an ethernet cable to the old one. I now have to networks (my devices get either `192.168.1.xxx` or `192.168.0.xxx` IP addreses). I want to find a way to merge these two networks if this is possible.

Could you please help me, guys?

Comment: Is your SSID the same on both devices or does the extender have a name like "SSID_ext"?

Comment: @Bungicasse they both have the same SSID

Comment: Do you know if your extender has DHCP running?

Comment: @Bungicasse yes, both have DHCP running, since I am getting two IP ranges

Comment: What happens if you turn of DHCP on your extender? Do your devices then get an IP from your router?